# Regex matches first letter of word and omit it

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to find regex example but can't seem to find one:
I am looking for regex to match first character of the word in string and if it matches, I want to omit it. For example

```
String example = "Blueberry strawberry peach Banana";
```

if first character or word starts with b or B - character sensitive doesn't matter, omit it and return only strawberry peach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex?

Comment: split by space and check if word sounds more reasonable

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to work around using regex.

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in `replaceAll`:

```
String input = "Blueberry strawberry peach Banana";

String repl = input.replaceAll("\\s*\\b[Bb]\\S*\\s*", "");
//=> strawberry peach
```

`\\s*\\b[Bb]\\S*\\s*` matches any word starting with `B` or `b` surrounded by 0 or more spaces on either side of the word.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
(?:^|\s+)(?![Bb])[^\s]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L0T2GJ/5)

Sample:

```
final String pat = "(?:^|\\s+)(?![Bb])[^\\s]*";
final String string = "Blueberry strawberry peach Banana kela lau bishu ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
while (m.find())
    if (!m.group(0).trim().isEmpty()) 
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

Comment: Or just `\b[^Bb]\S*`.

Comment: This works on http://regexr.com/ as expected. The "\b[^Bb]\S*" that Rawing suggested just separates the text with Bb into a separate match.

Comment: @JonathanSchmold You're right, my bad. But the `(?:^|\\s+)` in this regex could be replaced with `\b` for better readability and no downside (though then you also have to change the `*` to a `+` to prevent empty matches).

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "Blueberry strawberry peach Banana";
    String res ="";
    for(String word : example.split(" ")){
        if(!Pattern.matches("[Bb].*",word)){
            res += word+" ";
        }
    }
    res = res.substring(0, res.length()-1);
    //Print the result
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

You keep only the words wich don't match with your rule (here 'start with B or b')